# Add new column based in condition

Tags: awk

It is same question asked before, but I have changed the text for better understanding.

At begining of column 2 the same block (2000) have 3 lines, in the next block (2336) it have 9 lines and for block (2524) 3 lines.

In block (2336) which contend more than 3 lines. The value increase for column 1 is every 2, but when it is > 36. Then, from 3601 to 33607 (lower values) value in column 3 = S3 and for 34033 to 34041 (higher values) value in column 3 = S2

In the orignal file i have thousands of lines.

**You can consider that the input file have 3 parts:**

```
**PART1)** blocks of 3 lines ( 2000 -2005 ) value in colunm 3 = S2
**PART2)** blocks with more than 3 lines ( 2336 -2339 ) need to consider column 1 for the value in column 3 ( lower values = S3) ( higher values = S2) 
**PART3)** last blocks with 3 lines value in colunm 3 = S3..
```

**It is fundamental to check the values in column 1 when the block have more than 3 lines to define the value in column 3.**

**Input file**

```
30001 2000
30003 2000
30005 2000
30007 2005
30009 2005
30011 2005
33601 2336
33603 2336
33605 2336
33607 2336
34033 2336
34035 2336
34037 2336
34039 2336
34041 2336
33609 2339
33611 2339
33613 2339
34043 2339
34045 2339
34047 2339
34049 2339
35857 2524
35859 2524
35861 2524
35855 2527
35857 2527
35869 2527
```

**Output file**

```
30001 2000 S2
30003 2000 S2
30005 2000 S2
30007 2005 S2
30009 2005 S2
30011 2005 S2
33601 2336 S3
33603 2336 S3
33605 2336 S3
33607 2336 S3
34033 2336 S2
34035 2336 S2
34037 2336 S2
34039 2336 S2
34041 2336 S2
33609 2339 S3
33611 2339 S3
33613 2339 S3
34043 2339 S2
34045 2339 S2
34047 2339 S2
34049 2339 S2
35857 2524 S3
35859 2524 S3
35861 2524 S3
35855 2527 S3
35857 2527 S3
35869 2527 S3
```

**I tried**

```
awk '$3<0{c=3} {$3=(c-->0)?"S3":"S2"}1' tmp1 | tac | awk 'NR<=36 {$NF="S3"}1' | tac | awk '{print $2$1,$3}'
```

Apprecite your support.

Comment: the last block (2527) has 3 rows but marked as S3, shouldn't it be S2?

Comment: also, *contends* usually refers to competition. I'm assume you mean either ***contain*** or ***contents*** ("has the contents of"), so fixing that will help clarify your meaning. Good luck.

Comment: @OXXO, not clear to be honest, could you please do add more details in your question and let us know then?

Comment: Karakfa, No in the last blocks ( 2524-2527) the value in column 3 need to be S3, like the desired output results

Comment: I have add more details in the question, hope you can help

Comment: @OXXO, could you please elaborate how one will come to know `lower values` in 2nd case?

Comment: Ravinder, For the 2case example in block 2336, column 1 containds 33601-33607(lower values), 34033-34041(high values). The interval by line is 2 but in the case 33607-34033 is > 2 then there is 2 sets low and high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a solution with double scanning...

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {count[$2]++; n=NR; next} 
               {if(big && !jump) jump=$1-prev>2; 
                if($2!=block) {big=(count[$2]>3);jump=0}; 
                f=(big && !jump || n-FNR<3)?"S3 :"S2"; 
                print $0,f} {prev=$1;block=$2}' file{,}

30001 2000 S2
30003 2000 S2
30005 2000 S2
30007 2005 S2
30009 2005 S2
30011 2005 S2
33601 2336 S3
33603 2336 S3
33605 2336 S3
33607 2336 S3
34033 2336 S2
34035 2336 S2
34037 2336 S2
34039 2336 S2
34041 2336 S2
33609 2339 S3
33611 2339 S3
33613 2339 S3
34043 2339 S2
34045 2339 S2
34047 2339 S2
34049 2339 S2
35857 2524 S2
35859 2524 S2
35861 2524 S2
35855 2527 S3
35857 2527 S3
35869 2527 S3
```

now now penultimate block is marked with S3 instead of S2.  What is the logic?  How many last blocks does **PART3)** address?

I posted this knowing that it doesn't match the expected output to motivate some other person willing to help.

Comment: Karakfa, many thanks, the logic is in the PART1) will be 18 blocks, PART2) will be 5000 blocks , PART3) will be 18 blocks..

Comment: OK give it a try by changing `n-FNR<3` to `n-FNR<3*18`

Comment: Karakfa, your code is amazing and working perfeclty..  Is there the possiblity to detect the last blocks with 3 lines (PART3) automatic,  to avoid to use the option n-FNR<3*18.. The full file have 18 blocks but sometimes this can be < than 18. To check that the last blocks have 3 lines, Maybe it can works counting the total lines in column 2, then you will now when it change from PART2 to PART3.